# How to solve the equation $\cos x \cos 7x = \cos 5x \cos 3x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We were given the equation 
$$\cos x \cos 7x = \cos 5x \cos 3x.$$
 How can we solve it for $x$? So far I have solved only basic trigonometric equations, so I don't know how to reduce it to basic one.

Thanks in advance for some hints on how to solve the equation.

Comment: You can use the identity $\cos A \cos B=\frac{1}{2}( \cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B))$

Comment: Formally http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 4):

Using the linearisation identity mentioned in a comment, it is equivalent to the equation
$\cos 6x=\cos 2x$,. The solutions of the latter satisfy the congruences
$$6x\equiv\pm2x\mod 2\pi.$$
Can you end the computations and simplify the results?